# How to refresh DataContext of PivotItem after page navigation

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm, windows-phone

In a WP 7.1 project, I have a MainPage.xaml. In there I have a Pivot control from the WP Toolkit that looks like this:

```xml
<c:Pivot x:Name="pivot" Title="title">
    <c:PivotItem Header="header" DataContext="{vm:ListViewModel}">
        <v:ListView />
    </c:PivotItem>
    ...
</c:Pivot>
```

Basically, I am setting the contents of the first pivot item to a UserControl I created called ListView and created a view model for that called ListViewModel.

Using a simple model class like this:

```cs
public class MyModel {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The xaml for ListView view looks like this:

```xml
...
<ListBox x:Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding ModelItems"}>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.EditCommand, ElementName=list}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
...
```

Just a simple 2 line entry for each item in the list. Name is displayed in the first line and the button is for when we want to edit that item. The view model for this view is:

```cs
...
private ObservableCollection<MyModel> modelItems;
public ObservableCollection<MyModel> ModelItems {
    get { return modelItems; }
    set {
        if (modelItems != value) {
            modelItems = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(() => this.ModelItems);
        }
    }
}

public ListViewModel() {
    ModelItems = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>(repository.GetAll());
}

public ICommand EditCommand {
    get {
      return new RelayCommand(o => {
          var model = o as MyModel;
          Navigator.Uri<EditView>()
                   .WithParam("id", model.id)
                   .Navigate();
    }
}
...
```

So far everything works great, the list is correctly populated. Clicking the button correctly navigates to the EditView view passing the id of the chosen model item.

The EditView page is simple, just a text box and a save button. The view model for that looks similar to this:

```cs
...
public EditViewModel() { // ctor
    var id = GetQueryString("id");
    Model = repository.Get(id);
}
...
```

The Edit page works well, it saves changes back to db. However, after the save operation I do a `Navigator.GoBack()` and the old data is displayed there. How should I force my list to update the new changes while avoiding code-behind?

I was able to achieve that using the pivot control Loaded event in the MainPage code-behind as follows:

```cs
private void pivot_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    var selectedPivotItem = (PivotItem)pivot.SelectedItem;
    ((ListViewModel)selectedPivotItem.DataContext).Rebind();
}
```

I added a `Rebind()` method to my ListViewModel that basically does the same as the constructor does, fetch all data again and assign it to `ModelItems`

Is there a way to achieve this without having to write any code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am used to create a class called `AppLifeService` using the singleton pattern. In this object I store various properties for use in navigation between pages.

When you are in a page where you perform an action (edit/delete/create), just put the modified object in the `AppLifeService` in some property like `DeletedComment`.

Then in the previous page, in the `OnNavigatedTo` method, verify it's a navigate-back and search for your object.

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e, NavigationContext context, NavigationService navigationService)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e, context, navigationService);

        // back from other app page
        if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
        {
            var lifeService = ApplicationServices.Resolve<AppLifeService>();
```

nt?
                var deletedComment = lifeService.DeletedComment;
                if (deletedComment != null)
                {
                    // delete comment
                }

Make sure you don't store heavy objects to avoid clogging-up the memory. And delete them when used.